# Phaser game - get last frame of a sprite

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

I don't want to play animation,I want to chage sprite's frames by clicking right and left buttons.

```
var sprite = game.add.sprite(200, 100, 'mySprite');
sprite.frame = 3;
```

Now, if a right button is pressed I want this sprite goes to next frame

```
sprite.frame += 1;
```

If left button is pressed, sprites goes to the previous frame.

```
sprite.frame -= 1;
```

If left is pressed and current frame is 0 the sprite does not change it's frame, it stops on frame 0. I want the sprite goes from 0 to the last frame when I click left button.

For example, in Actionscript 3, I can do this:

sprite.gotoAndStop(sprite.totalFrames);

Is there "totalFrames" in Phaser/JS?

Comment: It would not be easier to use something like this? => https://phaser.io/examples/v2/animation/two-frame-test

Comment: @Julián I use something similar in platformers, as I said, when button is clicked, I want the sprite goes to the next/previous frame (to change one frame not to play animation), if sprite current frame is 0 and left is pressed, it should go to the last frame. I don't see how this example can help.

Comment: @Abadziluk try sprite.animations.frameTotal

Comment: @juvian That's it, I have already created a custom variable, but thank you, I will that in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not find any answer, I have created a custom variable 'totalFrames' for all objects. The first frame is 0, then 1 and so on...

```
if (rightClick)
{
   objects.frame += 1;
}
else if (leftClick)
{
   if (objects.frame > 0)
   {
      objects.frame -= 1;
   }
   else
   {
      objects.frame = objects.totalFrames;
   }
}
```

Comment: I'm just curious, what animation effect are trying to create? Do you use several sprite sheets with varying amounts of animation frames per sprite?

Comment: @BdR Yes, I use many spritesheets with different number of animation frames.

Comment: Don't you need a check in the first if condition so as to not exceed the number of totalFrames when incrementing objects.frame (as you have done with decrementing)?

Comment: @humbolight I had the same opinion, but if the sprite's frame is the last one and you click "right" to go the next frame, sprite displays the first frame (0). But it does not work if you are on the first frame and click left to go to the last frame. That's at least for me, you can try it by yourself.

Answer (score 0):

A bit late, buy you could try Phaser.GameObjects.Sprite.anims.getTotalFrames()